# Connect to wireguard server running on raspberry

Tags: raspbian, python, vpn, sockets, wireguard

I have installed `Wireguard` Server on my Raspberry Pi using `pivpn`. Everything works well except for one thing. The Raspberry server has an IP address of 10.6.0.1. I have a simple socket messenger written in Python. If I run the server of this messenger on my Raspberry Pi, which has an IP address of 10.6.0.1, then other clients of the VPN network cannot connect to it. Moreover, if I start the messenger server on a machine with an IP of 10.6.0.2, then other clients of the VPN network will be able to connect safely. The router has forwarded port 1776 for `wireguard` and 9090 for the messenger server. Is there any way to fix this? My wg0 config looks like this:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = private key
Address = 10.6.0.1/24
ListenPort = 1776

[Peer]
PublicKey = 5CxlSHSk/0i4FmqLq4xitCfVDXioW3oYOGpxsfunxXQ=
PresharedKey = preshared key
AllowedIPs = 10.6.0.2/32
```

Client config:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = private key
Address = 10.6.0.2/24
DNS = 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4

[Peer]
PublicKey = PFcJ1oSvCoIZxjxJzVk+aczXiYXE7wPiCDDXBjEMk1c=
PresharedKey = preshared key
Endpoint = mydomain.com:1776
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::0/0
```

Netstat outuput:

[image]

Comment: Your router would not (and could not) be forwarding port 9090 to 10.6.0.1, it would be forwarding to your regular LAN IP address (192.168.x.x most likely) - so, if your messenger server is only listening on 192.168.x.x then of course your messenger clients can't connect to 10.6.0.1 and expect to get connected

Comment: @Jaromanda X So is there any way to fix it?

Comment: no idea, because I have no idea what your messenger server is listening to ... do you know?

Comment: @Jaromanda X on the router the rule looks like ip=10.6.0.1 port=9090
And in the massager code there are these lines
host = 10.6.0.1
port = 9090

Comment: how does your router know what computer 10.6.0.1 is?

Comment: @Jaromanda X if so, why, when I start the messenger server on ip 10.6.0.2, then the client, for example, with ip 10.6.0.3 can safely connect to it?

Comment: because the client at 10.6.0.3 is in the same subnet as 10.6.0.2 ... but the router is unlikely to know where 10.6.0.1 is, unless you add a static route for 10.6.0.0/24 to the LAN ip (not the 10.6.0.1 ip) of the pi that has wireguard on it - but, the other way to fix this is to make sure that the message server is listening on 10.6.0.1 - is it? I think your issue is not understanding networking and how packets route from one subnet to another

Comment: @Jaromanda X yes you are right, I am a newbie in this theme, so I don’t have enough knowledge and I decided to ask for help from you

Comment: @Jaromanda X and yes message server is listening on 10.6.0.1

Comment: then anything on 10.6.0.x should be able to connect to it

Comment: @Jaromanda X yes, but it can’t connect. Maybe I’m doing wrong port forward, in router settings i have made the rule where I typed ip 10.6.0.1 and port 9090 and the second rule for wireguard is ip 192.168.1.198 (raspberry pi ip) and port 1776

Comment: the port forward is irrelevant for clients on 10.6.0.x

Comment: @Jaromanda X So how port forwarding should be done? Sorry for being annoying

Comment: for clients using wireguard - i.e. already on 10.6.0.x network ... port forwarding for your message server should not be needed ... anything on 10.6.0.x should be able to connect to 10.6.0.1 ... as long as the server is running on that IP address

Comment: @Jaromanda X but unfortunately they can’t connect to it. I have no idea why, because i am able to connect to 10.6.0.1 using ssh, but I can’t connect to messenger server:(

Comment: how do you know the messenger server is listening on 10.6.0.1?

Comment: @Jaromanda X If you want I can also add messenger code in my question

Comment: no, I want you to explain how you know it's listening on that IP address - does netstat show it's listening there?

Comment: @Jaromanda X I’m not sure. i will check when i get home

Comment: @Jaromanda X I added netstat output in my question post